# Lookup Column in two lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, angularjs

I have a situation on our team that requires us to redesign a set of lists. This directly relates to a client side development effort where we need to re-engineer a Custom Sharepoint Solution written in C# into an angularJS based application.

Our current Custom Sharepoint Solution used C# memory tables (System.Data.DataTable) to store and merge list data together. With client side programming REST and SPServices, this will be a risk due to decreased performance, if we were to pull 2 sets of list data and merge them to output data to HTML.

Now, we have thought of a few proposed solutions for a list redesign, but in some instances they don't seem to work well. For instance,

we have a user roster, a class list, a PostForClassesList and a CurriculumCourseslist. This history list stores current, past, and future assigned course data and completion information. CurriculumCoursesList stores all course data (location, instructor, Course title, etc). PostForClassList stores courses students post to take. An advisor would meet with a student to finalize their courses and approve them, moving those selected courses to Class List.

I have uploaded a proposed solution. We would like to have a few people with knowledge in lookup columns examine our solution and provide some comments or a better solution using lookup columns.

[image]

We want to ensure that we are using lookup columns correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: A few use cases that I did not include are: Courses by User report, User courses taken report, Current Postings Report, etc.